# Wpf sort or crud on datagrid cause reset checkbox

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I added column that has checkbox and when checkbox checked I get average of some numbers that selected.

The problem is when sorting data or do something to database cause all checkbox check status to false. How to fix it?

The only way I know is store that checkbox as boolean in database and everytime I run the program set all boolean to false. But that is not good way. Because in large data cause slowly down the performance of program.

Every time the database changed this code called for update DataGrid.

```
using DataContextTest dc=new();

DgTest.ItemsSource= dc.TestTable.ToList();
```

Comment: Please share code-behind logic. How do you sort data? Are you using ObservableCollection<T>? Add more details, so someone could help you.

Comment: use the column of datagrid. Press that button and then sorted. No more code for sort database.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using a ObservableCollection and once necessary action complete, SaveChages to the database. Then do your refresh or reload whatever. It seems, you are reloading the data, which is not necessary as long as the context is alive. Just make sure you are saving the new state of the collection to you DB (use that same context you used to load the data)
I hope it helps

Comment: Can you explain this with example? And one thing i don't want save checkbox value in database i just use it for receive some data from that row. After datagrid sorted or anything happened that cause datagrid.itemssource changed. That cause the reset of checkbox value

Comment: I am an Entity Framework, MVVM guy.
OK, if you dont want to save, it is OK. You may want to create a replacement collection on your viewModel. Simply repopulate that "virtual" collection with the real data on loading, then only use necessary columns to do so. Your heckbox boolean property will only eist in your vitual collection.
How you do it really depends on how you are loading the collection.
if you are Binding the checkbox column, any change will reflect on your collection too.

Comment: thanks for helping but i never use MVVM in any of my training project. because i don't know how to use MVVM. and i am learning it now. so i add my sample to first post. to show how i use EF for CRUD and Binding with DataGrid.

Comment: TestTable needs to have a property for the checkbox and it will remember the state even after sorting. Bind like this: IsChjecked="{Binding Path=yourcheckedpropertyname, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
By the way, you can also set the ItemsSource of the DataGrid to that collection you have. You can do that in code or xaml too

Comment: Thanks. I know that. But with that every time i open the program i have to set all boolean to false.